What is the purpose of the black hose and blue tube sticking out of this culvert in Norway?
While cycling along county road 2176 along the Trysil river in Central Norway, I noticed that most/many culverts had a black hose and a blue tube sticking out of them, such as in this photo:

What is the purpose of this contraption?  It appeared to be used systematically in (almost) all culverts but nowhere else.

Maybe they are going to put a lighting pole here? This may be electric wiring inside a conduit.

@Petr Why exactly at the culverts and nowhere else, though?

I'll have two guesses... 1) The blue tube is a guide to pull a drain pig through the black drainage pipe (keeps it open to get the pig line through).  Or 2) a hot-water duct to pump hot water through to melt whatever is frozen in the drain.
